# How to reverse options in Ant design Cascader component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, antd

The default behavior of Cascader is options' nesting goes from left to right. What I need is them to go from right to left. But could not find suck thing in API of component.

Is this even possible?

I tried placement:

```
export const MultiSelect = ({ placeholder }: MultiSelectProps): JSX.Element => {
return (
    <div>
        <Cascader
            options={options}
            size={'large'}
            style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', height: '48px' }}
            expandTrigger="hover"
            displayRender={displayRender}
            onChange={onChange}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            placement="bottomRight"
        />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The error TypeScript gives me:

> Type '{ options: { value: string; label: string; children: { value:
> string; label: string; children: { value: string; label: string; }[];
> }[]; }[]; size: "large"; style: { marginLeft: string; height: string;
> }; expandTrigger: "hover"; displayRender: (label: any) => any;
> onChange: (value: any) => void; placeholder: string;...' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> IntrinsicClassAttributes & Pick<Readonly &
> Readonly<...>, "placeholder" | ... 28 more ... | "transitionName"> &
> Partial<...> & Partial<...>'.   Property 'placement' does not exist on
> type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Pick<Readonly & Readonly<...>, "placeholder" | ... 28
> more ... | "transitionName"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 0):

If i completely understand what you are saying,
there is a attribute `placement` on Cascader. You can set it as `placement="bottomRight"` and the dialog going from right to left.

Comment: i tried but typescript is yelling that there is no such props so i can not do this

Comment: can you share image for that ? with Js in working fine

Comment: how do i send you ? you got Telegram or Slack ?

Comment: you can post it here is a part of a problem

Comment: sorry could not format code

Comment: add the error that typescript shows to u ?

Comment: added error to question